# Get get_attribute("value") after refresh the page

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently mu scenario is so:

1. send `send_keys` to a field
2. click in "save" button (refresh the page after click)
3. get `get_attribute("value")`after refresh the page

**My code:**

```
    def fill_twitter(self):

        enter_twitter = "http://" + fake.text(max_nb_chars=13) + ".com"

        twitter_field = self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.TWITTER)
        twitter_field.send_keys(enter_twitter)

        self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.SAVE_BUTTON).click()
        time.sleep(4)

        assert twitter_field.get_attribute("value") == enter_twitter
```

**My error:**

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

How can I get the `get_attribute("value")`?

Comment: You need to find again same element for getting their value as `self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.TWITTER).get_attribute("value")`..

Answer (score 2):

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

The [most frequent cause](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) of this is that page that the element was part of has been refreshed, or the user has navigated away to another page.

As you are saying page is getting refreshed when click on save button. Hence to avoid this you need to find same element (refresh element) again to getting their value as below :-

```
assert self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.TWITTER).get_attribute("value") == enter_twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

As the page got refreshed, you better save the value of the attribute before the element gets `Stale.`

```
def fill_twitter(self):

    enter_twitter = "http://" + fake.text(max_nb_chars=13) + ".com"

    twitter_field = self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.TWITTER)
    twitter_field.send_keys(enter_twitter)
    value = twitter_field.get_attribute("value")

    self.find_element(*ContractorsLocators.SAVE_BUTTON).click()
    time.sleep(4)

    assert value == enter_twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

To check element is visible after page is refreshed use explicit sleep() function and after 4 seconds check that component is visible or not using `WebDriverWait`.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"));
```

Visit http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits for better understanding.